# Using trackBy to only render DOM when a specific property changes on object in ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to setup `trackBy` for 2 `ngFor` iterators, these 2 were causing loading problems before, slowing down the app significantly because I had `row.getRows()` in ngFor. I changed it so the rows only retrieved in the component init and it fixed the problem, no more processing arrays every time the ngFor renders.

Now I need to update a cell property `isSelected` which occurs frequently on the mousemove event, it would probably cause same slow loading lagging effect. I think only rendering a DOM element if a single property changes could fix it so how can I only render a cell/td if the `isSelected` property of cell changes?

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngFor="let cell of row.cells">
    {{cell.value}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is smart enough to only update the DOM if values have changed.

That is, if `rows` changes, every `<tr>` in the table is recreated. If `row` changes, every `<td>` in that row is updated. If `cell.value` changes, the single text node for that cell is updated.

(changes means that `oldValue != newValue`. That is, objects are compared by identity, not content)

The problem with `getRows()` was that every call to `getRows()` likely returned a new Array object. That is, the `rows` always changed, and that's why angular recreated the entire table.

Long story short: trackBy is helpful if the array being iterated over changes, but the objects therein remain similar. Then, trackBy can tell angular how to match old to new objects, and reuse old DOM nodes, so only the changes within these objects cause DOM updates.

Comment: so not a new value but a new object re-initialised? like let rows: Grid[] = []; in getRows()?